# Manually editing a patch file (unified diff)

Tags: ubuntu, build, deb

I want to build an installer from source in Ubuntu (which works fine), but I need to alter one of the .patch-files in the source code. 
In the interesting part of this diff file I find

```
===================================================================
--- /dev/null   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 +0000
+++ pulseaudio-2.1/src/modules/module-nvs-detect.c  2013-05-03 18:47:21.791003759 -0300
@@ -0,0 +1,380 @@
+#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
+#include <config.h>
+#endif
+
(...)
```

I want to add a single line to this patch, but I get an error that the patch is not cleanly removed when trying to build the package.

```
$dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -rfakeroot -b
(...)
Patch 0110-add_nvs_detect_support.patch does not remove cleanly (refresh it or enforce with -f)
make: *** [reverse-patches] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
```

How can I edit this diff-header to appropriately add one extra line of code in the patch?

Comment: Why don't you edit the file itself and then diff it against the original file? Would be more clean than writing the patch itself.

Comment: There is no original file

Comment: Check the filename after the first +++, that's the filename against which the patch has been written.